# JSON bitmap data

Tags: jquery, .net, json

Is it possible, or reasonable, to encode bitmap data into JSON to be returned in a webservice?

Update:  Yes, this worked better than I thought.  I made a .NET composite object for a combination of images together with image data

Public Class AllThumbnails
        Public imgAllThumbs As String
        Public positions() As Drawing.Rectangle
End Class

and accessed it via jQuery AJAX thusly:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "WebService.asmx/makeAllThumbnailsImage",
    data: "{DocumentNumber : \"" + DocumentNumber + "\"} ",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        var adl = (typeof response.d) == 'string' ? eval('(' + response.d + ')') : response.d;

        var data = Base64.decode(adl.imgAllThumbs);
        $('#output').append("<p><strong>" + data.length + "</strong></p>");
        $('#output').append("<p><strong><i>" + adl.positions.length + "<i></strong></p>");

    },
    failure: function (msg) {
        $('#output').text(msg);
    }
});
```

I did have to increase a value in my web.config since my image data was overrunning the standard jsonSerialization buffer:

```
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="262144">
        </jsonSerialization>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
```

Thanks guys for your help.

Comment: Sorry -- should have said.  I'm using C# .NET and Javascript and jQuery.

Comment: it's no problem. All you have to do is edit your post and then add/remove tags as needed. I'm going to add them for you since this is an old post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A bitmap is binary data. JSON is to be represented as character data. So you need to convert binary data to character data and vice versa without loss of information. A commonly used encoding for this is [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). It's unclear which programming language you're targeting on, so I can't give a more detailed answer, but almost all self-respected languages have either a builtin Base64 encoder or a 3rd party library which can do that. PHP for example has [`base64_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) and [`base64_decode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php). Java has [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) [Base64](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html). For JavaScript there is [this example](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html). And so on.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like [Binary JSON](http://bsonspec.org/).

> Bin­ary JSON, is a bin­ary-en­coded seri­al­iz­a­tion of JSON-like
>   doc­u­ments. Like JSON, BSON sup­ports the em­bed­ding of doc­u­ments
>   and ar­rays with­in oth­er doc­u­ments and ar­rays. BSON also
>   con­tains ex­ten­sions that al­low rep­res­ent­a­tion of data types
>   that are not part of the JSON spec. For ex­ample, BSON has a Date type
>   and a BinData type.
>
> BSON can be com­pared to bin­ary inter­change for­mats, like Proto­col
>   Buf­fers. BSON is more "schema-less" than Proto­col Buf­fers, which
>   can give it an ad­vant­age in flex­ib­il­ity but also a slight
>   dis­ad­vant­age in space ef­fi­ciency (BSON has over­head for field
>   names with­in the seri­al­ized data).

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use a data uri (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) to decode encoded bitmap data... would be interesting to try :-)